# Do I need another IMU if my camera has IMU?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a 4 wheels robot.
The main chassis has a pan/tilt turret with a camera. The camera has an IMU sensor built in.
Should I have another IMU sensor to precisely drive the robot.
I am asking that since the IMU on camera might provide complex info if the robot is on the move while the turret rotates.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399195/do-i-need-another-imu-if-my-camera-has-imu?/) by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-04-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-18**:
It is a quite interesting question - I think there should be some problems with moving the camera with this IMU. How can you transform IMU measurements with rotated camera? What kind of camera model is it? This is [a nice roundup about IMU in robots](https://www.generationrobots.com/blog/en/imu-and-robotics-all-you-need-to-know-2/). I hope it will help you.

**Comment by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on 2022-04-19**:
Thanks. I think is more clear now that I need another IMU on the body of the robot.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-19**:
I'm glad to help with suggestions :)

**Comment by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on 2022-04-20**:
if you can wrap up your comment as an answer we can close the post

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-20**:
Okay, give me a moment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As in the previous comment:

> It is a quite interesting question - I
> think there should be some problems
> with moving the camera with this IMU.
> How can you transform IMU measurements
> with rotated camera? What kind of
> camera model is it?
>
> This is a nice roundup about IMU in
> robots:
>
> https://www.generationrobots.com/blog/en/imu-and-robotics-all-you-need-to-know-2/
>
> I hope it will help you.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1